# Python/atom: Is there an installable package that will enable the 'raw_input()' function?

Tags: python, atom-editor

Just looking for a package that allows the programmer to enter information after declaring a 'raw_input' function in a python program. Already have the code-running package installed for my project but am looking to expand my code. Please comment if such a package even exists! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `raw_input` is a built-in function in Python 2, it's been renamed to `input` in Python 3.

Comment: Hello, in python 2 you can use both raw_input() and input(). In python3 you can say str(input()) or int(input())

Comment: Already have a script package running in atom, however i was wondering if one exists that would allow you to enter information after using the raw_input() function. Not a big deal just wanted to check my syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Already have the code-running package installed

Which one? There are several. I know for a fact that `script`, `atom-runner`, and `process-palette` aren't set up to handle user input. Until/unless they add that feature, what you're looking for is a terminal package. There are a few of them. [`script-runner`](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) resolves into a terminal, while packages like [`termination`](https://atom.io/packages/termination) and [`atom-terminal-tab`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal-tab) generate terminals that you can do whatever you want with.